# How to pass a vue.js value as a parameter to a route in blade

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5, vue.js

I have a route in Laravel that requires an id as a parameter.

```
Route::get('/example/{id}', ExampleController@index)
```

If I had passed the data from the Laravel controller to the view value I would pass it like this:

```
<a href="/example/{{id}}" class="button success">Click</a>
```

But my `id` is a `vue` value:

```
<tr v-for="item in items">
            <td>@{{ item.id }}</td>
            <td>@{{ item.name }}</td>
            <td>@{{ item.number }}</td>
            <td>@{{ item.address}}</td>
            <td v-if="item.status==0"><a href="/example/@{{item.id}}" class="button success">Click</a></td>
        </tr>
```

Which is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use [v-bind](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind) for this, like following:

```
<a :href="'/example/' + item.id" class="button success">Click</a>
```

Comment: @PhillisPeters Updated.